# OrderBy extension method for NPoco.Linq

Tags: c#, linq, npoco

I want to use OrderBy("columnName").

I see that it is possible by writing an extension method or using reflection.

I am using NPoco and I am unable to write an extension method.

```
IQueryProvider<Sample> query =  DbConnection.Query<Sample>();
```

I want to do:

```
var res = query.OrderByField("columnName");
```

I want to use something similar to this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string SortField, bool Ascending)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField);
    var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
    string method = Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
    Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
    var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
}
```

The above wont work since I am passing IQueryProvider instead of IQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
public static IQueryProvider<T> OrderByField<T>(this IQueryProvider<T> q, string SortField, bool Ascending)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField);
    string methodName = Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
    Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(prop, typeof(object));
    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(conversion, param);
    object result = typeof(IQueryProvider<T>).GetMethods().Single(
            method => method.Name == methodName)
        .Invoke(q, new object[] { lambda });
    return (IQueryProvider<T>)result;
}
```

Then apply the query.

```
var list = db.Query<Users>().OrderByField("Id",false).ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting "The type argument for method cannot be inferred from usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly".

Comment: Would you share your query ?

Comment: DbConnection.Query<Sample>().OrderByField("Id", false).ToList();
I have also tried and got error:
DbConnection.Query<Sample>().OrderByField<Sample>("Id", false).ToList();
"Does not contain definition for  OrderByField"

Comment: I have just tested it. It seems good. What is the declaration of "DbConnection"